# "File to import not found or unreadable: ~bootstrap/scss/functions.", "formatted": "Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ~

Tags: django, reactjs, npm, bootstrap-4

I am trying to run a project , I am unable to get css files loaded to the login webpage.I found this error in the npm build ,At the same time I find this issues unable to load the images though they are present in my folders.

I am pretty new to the frontend let me know if I need to provide any other file configurations

[image]

"file": "/Users/mthippareddygari/Documents/GitHub/workflow/node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/scss/_variables.scss",
  "line": 56,
  "column": 1,
  "message": "File to import not found or unreadable: ~bootstrap/scss/functions.",
  "formatted": "Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ~bootstrap/scss/functions.\n

Web.config

```
 module : {
    rules : [
        {
            test: /\.jsx/,
            include: APP_DIR,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            //Just in case
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        //{include: /\.json$/, loaders: ["json-loader"]}
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need some css (or less/sass) specific loaders for webpack to properly load your styles e.g.

```
           {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
```